# Long code line continuation method in GAP language

Tags: gap-system

Take the following code snippet as an example:

```
f:= FreeGroup("P","Q","R","S");
AssignGeneratorVariables(f);
g:= f/ParseRelators(f, "P^12=Q^4=R^4=S^8=1, Q^2=R^2, S^2 = P^6*Q^2*R,
Q*P=P^7*Q^2*R, Q*P^3=P^3*Q, R*P=P^10*Q*R, R*Q=P^6*Q^3*R, S*P=P^2*R*S,
S*Q=P^3*Q^3*R*S, S*R=R*S" );
```

I'm not sure if there is a long code line continuation method
implemented in GAP language.

Edit: Based on the nice tricks and tips given by Olexandr and Horn, I would like to add some corresponding supplementary information as follows:

1. "Triple Quoted Strings" is described [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap27.html#X7E70384E7D0B7083).
2. The handling mechanism of line continuation, i.e., backslash followed by new line, is described [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X866092F281910B74).
3. In addition, the gap source code also includes the following description:

```sh
$ ugrep -i 'line continuation.*backslash'
bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-default64-kv8/src/io.c:    // handle line continuation, i.e., backslash followed by new line; and
src/io.c:    // handle line continuation, i.e., backslash followed by new line; and
```

Regards,
HZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not with the command occupying several lines, but with the string including a line break, as the error message says:

```
gap> g:= f/ParseRelators(f, "P^12=Q^4=R^4=S^8=1, Q^2=R^2, S^2 = P^6*Q^2*R,
Syntax error: String must not include <newline>
g:= f/ParseRelators(f, "P^12=Q^4=R^4=S^8=1, Q^2=R^2, S^2 = P^6*Q^2*R,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You have to use backslash `\` to continue the string from a new line. This input works:

```
f:= FreeGroup("P","Q","R","S");
AssignGeneratorVariables(f);
g:= f/ParseRelators(f, "P^12=Q^4=R^4=S^8=1, Q^2=R^2, S^2 = P^6*Q^2*R,\
Q*P=P^7*Q^2*R, Q*P^3=P^3*Q, R*P=P^10*Q*R, R*Q=P^6*Q^3*R, S*P=P^2*R*S,\
S*Q=P^3*Q^3*R*S, S*R=R*S" );
```

You can also use spaces as you like to indent and format it, e.g.

```
f:= FreeGroup("P","Q","R","S");
AssignGeneratorVariables(f);
g:= f/ParseRelators(f, 
"P^12  = Q^4 = R^4 = S^8 = 1,  \
 Q^2   = R^2, S^2 = P^6*Q^2*R, \
 Q*P   = P^7*Q^2*R,            \
 Q*P^3 = P^3*Q,                \
 R*P   = P^10*Q*R,             \
 R*Q   = P^6*Q^3*R,            \
 S*P   = P^2*R*S,              \
 S*Q   = P^3*Q^3*R*S,          \
 S*R   = R*S" );
```

or so.

Comment: Thank you for your nice trick. I wonder why `g:= f/ParseRelators(f` shouldn't be written as `g:= f/ParseRelators(f, \\` here.

Comment: @HongyiZhao The backslash is needed when GAP *objects* do not fit on one line, e.g. big integers, long strings or long identifiers (as the manual section now linked from the OP explains). Otherwise, GAP commands may occupy several lines, and new line characters are just treated as whitespace characters. In `g:= f/ParseRelators(f,` the new line does not break a string in the middle.

Comment: Another question: how can I display the `g:= f/ParseRelators(f, \\` with the code style? I mean, the content includes a backslash at the end, which seems will escape the backtick mark here.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure - markdown rendering in comments and the body of the question may also be different.

Comment: As you can see, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I suspect that's a limitation of markdown support in comments.

Comment: Agreed. The comments in itself is convenient only designed for short point of views, but not for complicated descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the nice answer by Olexandr, let me mention that you can also use triple quoted strings to avoid the need for line continuations. E.g. like this:

```
f:= FreeGroup("P","Q","R","S");
AssignGeneratorVariables(f);
g:= f/ParseRelators(f, """
 P^12  = Q^4 = R^4 = S^8 = 1,
 Q^2   = R^2, S^2 = P^6*Q^2*R,
 Q*P   = P^7*Q^2*R,
 Q*P^3 = P^3*Q,
 R*P   = P^10*Q*R,
 R*Q   = P^6*Q^3*R,
 S*P   = P^2*R*S,
 S*Q   = P^3*Q^3*R*S,
 S*R   = R*S
""" );
```

Comment: Nice trick again.